# Vector of Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a vector of vectors is there a way to find the size of the vector going horizontally? Currently I'm only getting sizes 4 and then 3 when I just want a size of 2.

```
[num1][num2]
[num3][num6]
[num4][num7]
[num5]

ruleList[0][0] = [num1]
ruleList[1][0] = [num2]
ruleList[0][1] = [num3]

for(int j = 0; j < ruleList[j].size(); j++)
{
}
```

ruleSize[0].size() prints out a 4 while ruleList[1].size() prints out a 3 according to the sample vector above. What I want is it to print out 2 which takes into account [num1] and [num2]. If I were to add another element it would be:

```
[num1][num2][num8]
[num3][num6]
[num4][num7]
[num5]
```

In this case, it should return size of 3 (taking into account [num1], [num2], and [num8])

My current vector is formatted as such:

```
vector< vector<string> > ruleList(100, vector<string> (0, "0"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by sizes 4, 3 and 2?

Comment: Sizes 4 and 3 are the sizes respectively going vertically.  I just want the size for the first element of the vector going horizontally, which is my example should be 2.

Comment: Please post the code to print 4, 3 and 2 so we can reproduce it, and understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Going "vertically" and "horizontally" are subjective. Do you want the amount of inner vectors: `ruleList.size()` or a specific inner vector?

Comment: ruleList[1].size() prints out a 3 while ruleSize[0].size() prints out a 4, which are the vertically columns specified in the example vectors above.

Comment: I've edited the original post to add more clarity.

Comment: Might it be, that you just have to swap the indices: `ruleList[0][1]` is the second element in the first vector of `ruleList` (and would be `[num2]` in your example if I got your example right). But `ruleList[1][0]` is the first element in the second vector in `ruleList`.

Answer (score 1):

You are filling the vector in wrong way

```
ruleList[0][0] = [num1]
ruleList[1][0] = [num2]
ruleList[0][1] = [num3]
```

If you want this :

```
[num1][num2][num8]
[num3][num6]
[num4][num7]
[num5]
```

just do this :

```
 vector< vector<string> > ruleList={{"num1","num2","num8"},
                                      {"num3","num6"},
                                      {"num4","num7"}};
```

or :

```
vector< vector<string> > ruleList(3);
ruleList[0]={"num1","num2","num8"};
ruleList[1]={"num3","num6"};
ruleList[2]={"num4","num7"};
```

now `ruleList[0].size()` return 3

Answer (score 0):

If ruleList is the name of the vector, `ruleList.size()` should give you the "horizontal" distance.

Comment: I've added a little more clarity above. Let me know if it's still confusing.